# Run two parallel cmd from single batch file ?

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I want to run two python files from a batch file in parallel I want each one to be executed in a separate cmd because they take time to finish and I want them to run in parallel is there away to do it ?

Comment: If you want a more advanced solution you could run them from python by using the `subprocess` module (or migrate the whole batch file to a python script). That way you could more easily(?) wait for them to complete before continue the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

`start` runs your script in a new shell.

```
start "" script1.py
script2.py
```

runs them in parallel, but note that there is no (easy) way to resynchronize, ie. wait in the calling batch for script1.py to complete.

(the empty quotes after start are for an optional window title argument to `start`, if you omit them and enclose your script path in quotes because it contains spaces, then start would take that erroneously as window title)

Comment: the title is not optional - "`title` - Text for the CMD window title bar (required.)". See [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Comment: that's simply wrong. type help start in the cmd window. or just try `start cmd.exe`

Comment: I find http://ss64.com more reliable than MS documentation - for one thing it covers all the bugs and limitations. But you're correct, it goes on to advise "Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like "My Script" or just a pair of empty quotes ""
According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but depending on the other options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted."